# Set condition for axis.text.x in general theme() in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes

I am working on creating a unified theme for a large project including many different types of plots.  I have set an overall theme where the angle for axis.text.x.bottom is 0 (horizontal), however some of my x-axis labels are quite long.  I would like to set the angle of axis.text.x.bottom equal to 0 for labels of length less than 3 and equal to 90 (read bottom to top) for labels of length greater than 3, without having to specify the theme for each individual plot.

*** this is a highly simplified example

```r
library(ggplot2)
report_theme(axis.text.x.bottom = element_text(angle = 0))

testdata1 = matrix(NA, nrow = 10, ncol = 2)
testdata1[,1] = 1:10
testdata1[,2] = 1:10

testdata1 = as.data.frame(testdata1)

g1 = ggplot(testdata1, aes(x = testdata1[,1], y = testdata1[,2])) + geom_point()
g1 + report_theme


testdata2 = testdata1
testdata2[,1] = c("number 1", "number 2", "number 3", "number 4", "number 5", "number 6", "number 7", "number 8", "number 9", "number 10")

g2 = ggplot(testdata, aes(x = testdata2[,1], y = testdata2[,2])) + geom_point()
g2 + report_theme
```

[image: testdata1 plot]

[image: testdata 2 plot]

The plot for testdata1 looks fine since the x-axis labels are numbers, however the x-axis labels for testdata2 are long strings, and hence can't easily be read horizontally because they overlap.

I know how to change the angle for each plot individually, but it requires knowing the name of the data frame being used to plot, and I would like to be able to do it within the overall theme report_theme.  How can I do this when a different data frame is being used for each plot?